How to find the local maximum and minimum of a function
I am trying to find the local maximum and minimum of a function. The code below works if function is an exponential but when function involves a sinusoid, it does not give numerical values and instead outputs complex conditional expressions. I am unsure what is missing? Do I need to add the domain?
tt = 3;
(*f[t_]:=3\[ExponentialE]^(-2t)-4\[ExponentialE]^(-3t)+\[ExponentialE]\
^(-5t);*)
f[t_] := 3 E^(-2 t) Sin[3 t]
NSolve[D[f[t], t] == 0, t, PositiveReals]
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, tt}]

Thank you so much. When the function is a simple exponential, then the code suggested dosent seem to pick up the maximum value to t=0. Can you please help. Also, the plotting dosent seem to work as well.
Clear["Global`*"]
tt = 3;
f[t_] := 2 E^(-1000 t) 
cpts = SortBy[N][
   Solve[{D[f[t], t] == 0, 0 <= t <= tt}, t] // Simplify];
cpts // N;
#[{f[t], 0 <= t <= tt}, t] & /@ {Minimize, Maximize} // FullSimplify;
% // N
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, tt}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{t, f[t]} /. cpts]}]


: dosent seem to pick up the maximum value to t=0": Is it this?: You need to check end points, not just stationary points (crit. pts.)? They made a big deal of it in my AP calc class. They seemed to think everyone always forgets that.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

tt = 3;

f[t_] := 3  E^(-2  t)  Sin[3  t]
cpts = SortBy[N][Solve[{D[f[t], t] == 0, 0 <= t <= tt}, t] // Simplify]

(* {{t -> 2/3 ArcTan[1/3 (-2 + Sqrt[13])]}, 
    {t -> 2/3 (π + ArcTan[1/3 (-2 - Sqrt[13])])}, 
    {t -> 2/3 (π + ArcTan[1/3 (-2 + Sqrt[13])])}} *)

cpts // N

(* {{t -> 0.327598}, {t -> 1.3748}, {t -> 2.42199}} *)

EDIT: Alternatively,
#[{f[t], 0 <= t <= tt}, t] & /@ {Minimize, Maximize} // FullSimplify

(* {{-((9 E^(-(4/3) (π - ArcTan[1/3 (2 + Sqrt[13])])))/Sqrt[
   13]), {t -> 2/3 (π - ArcTan[1/3 (2 + Sqrt[13])])}}, {(
  9 E^(-(4/3) ArcTan[1/3 (-2 + Sqrt[13])]))/Sqrt[
  13], {t -> 2/3 ArcTan[1/3 (-2 + Sqrt[13])]}}} *)

% // N

(* {{-0.159639, {t -> 1.3748}}, {1.29635, {t -> 0.327598}}} *)

Plot[f[t], {t, 0, tt},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{t, f[t]} /. cpts]}]


f2[t_] := 3 E^(-2 t) - 4 E^(-3 t) + E^(-5 t);

(cpts2 = Solve[D[f2[t], t] == 0, t, Reals]) // InputForm

(* {{t -> Log[Root[5 - 12*#1^2 + 6*#1^3 & , 2, 0]]}, 
    {t -> Log[Root[5 - 12*#1^2 + 6*#1^3 & , 3, 0]]}} *)

cpts2 // ToRadicals // Simplify

(* {{t -> Log[
    1/12 (8 + (8 I 2^(2/3) (I + Sqrt[3]))/(-13 + 3 I Sqrt[95])^(1/3) + 
       (-1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-26 + 6 I Sqrt[95])^(1/3))]}, 
    {t -> Log[1/6 (4 + (8 2^(2/3))/(-13 + 3 I Sqrt[95])^(1/3) + 
       (-26 + 6 I Sqrt[95])^(1/3))]}} *)

cpts2 // N

(* {{t -> -0.160173}, {t -> 0.540866}} *)

EDIT: Alternatively,
#[{f2[t], -3/10 <= t <= tt}, t] & /@ {Minimize, Maximize} // Simplify

(* {{1/125  (780 - 237  Root[180 - 12 #^2 + #^3& , 2, 0] + 
     16  Root[180 - 12 #^2 + #^3& , 2, 0]^2), {t -> Log[
Root[5 - 12 #^2 + 6 #^3& , 2, 0]]}}, {1/
   125  (780 - 237  Root[180 - 12 #^2 + #^3& , 3, 0] + 
     16  Root[180 - 12 #^2 + #^3& , 3, 0]^2), {t -> Log[
Root[5 - 12 #^2 + 6 #^3& , 3, 0]]}}} *)

% // N

(* {{-0.107374, {t -> -0.160173}}, {0.294398, {t -> 0.540866}}} *)

Plot[f2[t], {t, -1, tt},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{t, f2[t]} /. cpts2]}]


EDIT 2:
f[t_] := 2  E^(-1000  t)

The derivative is not zero for any finite value of t
cpts = Solve[D[f[t], t] == 0, t]

(* {} *)

The min and max occur at the boundaries of the interval
cpts = #[{f[t], 0 <= t <= tt}, t] & /@ {Minimize, Maximize} // FullSimplify

(* {{2/E^3000, {t -> 3}}, {2, {t -> 0}}} *)

 Plot[f[t], {t, 0, tt},
 PlotRange -> All,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{t, f[t]} /. cpts[[All, 2]]]},
 ImageSize -> 300]



Thank you so much. When the function is a simple exponential, then the code dosent seem to pick up the maximum value to t=0. Can you please help. Also, the plotting dosent seem to work as well.
Clear["Global`*"]
tt = 3;
f[t_] := 2 E^(-1000 t)
cpts = SortBy[N][
Solve[{D[f[t], t] == 0, 0 <= t <= tt}, t] // Simplify];
cpts // N;
#[{f[t], 0 <= t <= tt}, t] & /@ {Minimize, Maximize} // FullSimplify;
% // N
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, tt},
Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{t, f[t]} /. cpts]}]

You should not assume that code given in response to a question can be blindly applied to a different question. Plotting 2 E^(-1000 t) over some intervals clearly shows that the behavior of function is radically different  from the other examples.

Thank you for the comprehensive responses. The problem is solved now.

Example for domain $(0,2\pi)$ coloring maximum green and minimum red:
f[t_] := 3  E^(-2  t)  Sin[3  t]
sol = Solve[{D[f[t], t] == 0, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi}, t];
mm = Sign[D[f[t], {t, 2}]] /. sol;
p = {t, f[t]} /. sol;
pts = Thread[{p, 
     mm}] /. {{a_, 1} :> {Red, Point[a]}, {b_, -1} :> {Green, 
      Point[b]}};
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Epilog -> pts, PlotRange -> All]


